# How to prove that $\text {GL} (E)$ is an open subset of $\mathcal L (E)\ $?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

> Prove that if $E$ is Banach space then $\text {GL} (E)$ is an open subset of $\mathcal L (E).$

Here $\text {GL} (E)$ denotes the space of all bounded invertible linear operators on $E$ with bounded inverse and $\mathcal L (E)$ is the space of all bounded linear operators on $E.$

Let $T \in \text {GL} (E).$ We need to show that there exists an open ball $B(T, r)$ surrounding $T$ with radius $r \gt 0$ such that $B(T,r) \subseteq \text {GL} (E).$ Let $S \in B(T,r).$ If we can show that $\|I - S \|_{\text {op}} \lt 1$ then we are through. But how do I prove that? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to convince yourself that the implication $S \in B(T,r) \implies \|I - S\|_{\mathrm{op}} < 1$ does **not** hold for *every* $T \in GL(E)$. For instance, what if $T = -I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $S$ is necessarily invertible if $I - T^{-1}S = T^{-1}(T - S)$ has a sufficiently small operator norm.

Comment: But sir I want $S$ to be invertible. Am I right?

Comment: @Phibetakappa I completely mixed up what I meant to say; see my latest edit

Comment: Oh! I see now. If we take $r = \frac {1} {\|T\| + 1}$ then we have $B(T,r) \subseteq \text {GL} (E).$